# exc_bad_access(code=1 adress=0x68) in c90 program

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, c89

I'm trying to make a program in c90 which will read some words from a txt file and copy them to a matrix array. It seems that the compilation is all right but there is a thread named "EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1 adress=0x68). can you help me figure out where the problem is??

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

FILE *input;
char words[10][30];
int i,a;

input=fopen("test.txt","rt");
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    a = fscanf(input,"%s", words[i]);
    printf("%2d %s\n", a, words[i]);

    }
fclose(input);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: `words` or `word`? this doesn't even compile...

Comment: words I edited...mistake while copying!...now?

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>` and check `input != NULL`

Comment: @user32XXXX sounds like a buffer overflow. Lines can easily be longer than 30 characters. Also, `fscanf()` (and the entire `scanf()` familiy of functions, in fact) is a disaster. Use a funciton that you can use to check and/or limit the buffer length, e. g. `fgets()`.

Comment: there isn't an overflow i checked the words on the txt file.Im sure that is a disaster but i have to figure it out with the scanf() func.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that your file is actually being opened, otherwise printf() will try to print out random memory which may go beyond the bounds of what you have actually allocated and cause an error.

```
input = fopen("test.txt", "rt");
if (!input)
{
    perror("Failed to open file");
    exit(1);
}
```

You may also want to check that `a == 1`, i.e. that the `fscanf()` also succeeds.